# Django formsets: remove invalid forms

Tags: django, formsets

I am having trouble getting this accomplished. I have one formset with 5 extra forms. Those 5 forms have a non-required but pre-filled field (requirement). Formset always raises error when submitting which is normal as it sees all the forms as has_changed. I want to be able to ignore the forms that are partially filled but with mandatory fields empty.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: this validation issue wont rise if you set the values using initial attribute. Can you share some code?

Comment: @karthikr The code is pretty generic but the pre-filled values are actually filled using javascript. The value for the field in first row is copied down to all rows on "blur". If you still need code I'd happy to share but it won't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling formset.is_valid() Loop through forms and validate each form, only when it meet specific requirement that you have, ie:

```
for form in formset.forms:
    if (form.data['required_field']):
          form.is_valid()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I would not be able to delete the forms marked to be deleted when updating using this method. I've to call formset.save() later on to delete the forms marked to be deleted and calling formset.save() raises error.

Comment: good point - did not think of that. But in that case you have to handle saving individual forms and deleting them (I think you just have to check if DELETE field is selected for each one in your case that meets requirements.

Comment: Thank you @bmigelac, I guess that's one way to do it. Here's what I did: http://pastebin.com/5gxfcq9i

Comment: welcome, you could use form._raw_value('DELETE') to avoid handling prefix manually:  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L250

Comment: That's much cleaner. Thanks again!